# Redirecting to specific aspx page

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm making a asp.net project and in one aspx page i have a problem.
There are two choices to go, Bug and Change Request. On website if you click on bug you should go to IssueDetails.aspx or if you click Change Request you should go to ChangeDetails.aspx. Here is my a href code:

```
 <a href="IssueDetail.aspx?IssueID=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Id") %>"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title") %>  </a>
```

I'm checking the selected type name like this:

```
 <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Type.Name").ToString()=="Change Request" ? "go to IssueDetail.aspx" : "go to ChangeDetail.aspx"%>
```

How can i do these two parts "go to IssueDetail.aspx" and "go to ChangeDetail.aspx"
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
HyperLink issue=new HyperLink();
HyperLink change=new HyperLink();


<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Type.Name").ToString()=="Change Request" ? issue.NavigateURL="IssueDetail.aspx" : change.NavigateURL="ChangeDetail.aspx"%>
```

Comment: but it doesnt see the hyperlink, where should i extactly define them? @Aravin

Comment: @fstkk, it is to generate dynamic hyperlink. read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.navigateurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)